# cabal repl outputs a lot of changing git HEADs on plutus-pioneer-program

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cabal

This is a question regarding the plutus-pioneer-program. I want to load the modules of a given week into the ghci shell. The first time I run `cabal repl` it takes quite a long time to download things and by the looks, it clones git repos of some sort. I didn't copy the exact output. Then each time I run `cabal repl` the output tells me something about the git HEAD moving all over the place. I don't know what to make of it, since in the videos that accompany the program I do not see similar output, which makes me wonder whether I have set it up correctly. Here is the context and the output I get.

First I have checked out the commit with SHA1 hash *41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a* in the plutus-apps repo. Then I ran `nix-shell` and then changed directory to the `plutus-pioneer-program/code/week02`. I ran `cabal repl` and get the following output:

```
[nix-shell:~/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week02]$ cabal repl
HEAD is now at ee59880 Don't use the unsafe decodeUtf8
HEAD is now at 3825d3a Merge pull request #9 from input-output-hk/coot/createNamedPipe-error
HEAD is now at d2f86caa Merge pull request #149 from input-output-hk/rvl/adp-1114/fix-npm-publish
HEAD is now at 654f5b7 Merge pull request #240 from input-output-hk/nc/rewrite
HEAD is now at f730793 Merge pull request #69 from newhoggy/add-ghc-8.6.5-and-8.10.2-to-ci
HEAD is now at bf008ce02 Merge pull request #2526 from input-output-hk/jc/fix-alonzo-txwits-again
HEAD is now at 4f65fb9a2 Bump to version 1.32.1
HEAD is now at bb4ed71 Merge pull request #158 from input-output-hk/nc/drop-strict
HEAD is now at 760140e23 Merge #3063
HEAD is now at cde90a2 Re-enable support for GHC 8.6.5
HEAD is now at 46f994e Merge pull request #623 from input-output-hk/cda_490_kafka_backend
HEAD is now at d613de3d8 Merge #3479
HEAD is now at 2721c59fd [Builtins] Drop 'SomeConstantOf' and remove obsolete golden files (#4218)
HEAD is now at 6aff97d59 Update client deps to fix playground (#247)
HEAD is now at 366fc70 Add support for set and map json
HEAD is now at ebea59c Fix encoding
Build profile: -w ghc-8.10.4.20210212 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - plutus-pioneer-program-week02-0.1.0.0 (lib) (first run)
Preprocessing library for plutus-pioneer-program-week02-0.1.0.0..
GHCi, version 8.10.4.20210212: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Ok, 9 modules loaded.
Prelude Week02.Burn>
```

What's all those changing git HEADs about?